# How do I optimize a nested for loop using data.table?

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, apply

I am interested in optimizing some code using data.table. I feel I should be able to do better than my current solution, and it does not scale well (as the number of rows increase).

Consider I have a matrix of values, with ID denoting person and the remaining values are traits (lineage in my case). I want to create a logical matrix which reflects if two ID's (rows) share any values amongst their row (including ID). I have been using data.table lately, but I cannot figure out how to do this more efficiently. I have tried (and failed) at nesting apply statements, or somehow using the .SD function of data.table to accomplish this.

The working code is below.

```
m <- matrix(rep(1:10,2),nrow=5,byrow=T)
m[c(1,3),3:4] <- NA
dt <- data.table(m)
setnames(dt,c("id","v1","v2","v3"))
res <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=5,ncol=5)
dimnames(res) <- list(dt[,id],dt[,id])
for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){
  for (j in i:nrow(dt)){
    res[j,i] <- res[i,j] <-length(na.omit(intersect(as.numeric(dt[i]),as.numeric(dt[j])))) > 0 
  }
}
res
```

Comment: See if `outer` could offer any speed increase. Something like `outer(1:nrow(m), 1:nrow(m), Vectorize(function(x, y) length(na.omit(intersect(m[x, ], m[y, ]))) > 0))`

Comment: Can you give more details: are values in the matrix integers / double / character; what is the size of a matrix; what is the number of unique values in the matrix?

Comment: In the example posted, all values are integers and the matrix (m) is 5x5. In my real data values are character, and the matrix is 710x710. I think I can adapt a solution for the example to my real data, and hopefully I made this small/general enough others may find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago and somebody helped me out.  Here's that help converted to your problem...

```
tm<-t(m) #transpose the matrix
dtt<-data.table(tm[2:4,]) #take values of matrix into data.table
setnames(dtt,as.character(tm[1,])) #make data.table column names
comblist<-combn(names(dtt),2,FUN=list) #create list of all possible column combinations
preresults<-dtt[,lapply(comblist, function(x)     length(na.omit(intersect(as.numeric(get(x[1])),as.numeric(get(x[2]))))) > 0)] #recreate your double for loop
preresults<-melt(preresults,measure.vars=names(preresults)) #change columns to rows
preresults[,c("LHS","RHS"):=lapply(1:2,function(i)sapply(comblist,"[",i))] #add column labels
preresults[,variable:=NULL] #kill unneeded column
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to get my `preresults` to be in the same format as your `res` but this should give you the performance boost you're looking for.